# GPS PPS stable signal

Tags: gps

My question concerns the GPS NMEA reading data about PPS signal.

Is there any way to know via software using NMEA that the GPS PPS signal provided by its outport is already synchronized with the one of the satellite?

Does it mean that when the GPS outputs the GGA message with a valid position fix the PPS outputted is also stable, or should I wait for any specific command?

I notice that the epoch obtained by the GPS sometimes contains fractions of seconds and is sometimes an integer. What does this mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the operation of a commercial electronics module used by people on Earth and not about the exploration of space or GPS satellite operation

Comment: Hi @peter and *Welcome to Space!* There are [almost 200 Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to choose from and I think this is the wrong site for your question to be posted. Have a look at [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) or [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) and see if you can find existing answers that are helpful first.

Comment: If you don't find answers, then choose one site and post a question, but you should be sure to add more information first. The statement "I notice that the epoch obtained by the GPS sometimes contains fractions of seconds and is sometimes an integer. What does this mean?" should be clarified even further; what GPS module are you using, how are you viewing the data, etc. It would be really helpful to **show your data** within the question post, if you don't people will probably ask to see it, and that just slows things down. *Good luck!*

Comment: how stable is the 1 PPS https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sara-list/iPfGb9dSHw8/VuV_27e6BQAJ